# infinite loop VS sheduler

Tags: kernel, interrupt

From assembler point of view, when we make a code that just jumps a few commands back, does not jump to any control function that sheduler might use, how can unix interrupt such a code?

I assume it is using timer and interruptions. So the question is then can we implement unix system on a hardware without interruptions, and still solve the infinite loop code, in finite time?

Or in other words, am I right to assume that the only way unix can deal with code like 'while(true){}' is through hardware timer with interrupts?

And if so, what is a minimum requirement for implementing unix-like system on a hardware without hardware timer+interrupts?

Comment: I think easiest way to avoid hardware interrupts is to isolate a core and run this process on it. If you're running single-cored and this is the only process, you don't really need an OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is an Interrupt handled in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5788/how-is-an-interrupt-handled-in-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you discuss is the difference between non-preemptive and preemptive scheduling.

non-preemptive (also called cooperative) is a bit simpler (no timer needed), and it does not need locks when threads communicate. Examples Apple Mac OS9 and earlier, I think early MS-Windows, many embedded systems, and micro-threads.

So yes a timer is needed. However for your question about simplest hardware. Unix needs an MMU and this is far more complex than a timer. (Actually there are Unix like systems that have no MMU and in a lot of situations they work the same (differences are: no security, no swap/paging)

Another way to allow task switching for the `while true` case. Is to use code injection. The compiler or loader will inject code to cooperatively yield. This can be hard to do: For a loader there may not be enough information to know where is is needed. It may break assumptions of atomicity. Given the right language and compiler, it **probably** could be done well. However I don't know of any examples.